# Update model behind DataGrid on ComboBox value changed

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, data-binding

I have a WPF gridview that I assign data to through an observableCollection. One of the properties on this object is an enum which is in turn displayed as a combobox. In my xaml I dont define any headers, i just set the item source.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DbSchemaDecoder.DisplayTableDefinitionView.TableDefinitionView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DbSchemaDecoder.DisplayTableDefinitionView"
             
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DbTableDefinitionController.TableTypeInformationRows}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DbTableDefinitionController.SelectedTypeInformationRow}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <local:IndexConverter x:Key="IndexConverter" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding 
                    Key="Delete"
                    Command="{Binding DbTableDefinitionController.DbDefinitionRemovedCommand}" />
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My problem is that when I change a value in the combobox the value is not changed in the model until I select a new row in the table. How can I make so that it is updated when the combobox is closed? Is it possible to get an event when an item in the combobox is hovered over? I can find multiple examples on how to do this if I define the headers myself, but I would like to keep them auto generated like now if possible.

Comment: How do you end up with a combobox in the auto generated column? And. Have you considered validation implications if you try and commit on change of a single property rather than the entire row?  ( Why row change is the default behaviour.)

Comment: I dont know, I assumed it was the default behavior for enums? Validation would not be a problem for my case, all combinations of values is allowed.

Comment: Could well be the default behaviour. I very rarely use ( or have seen used in live apps ) autogenerated datagrids.

Comment: If I want to specify the headers myself, I can not use an observable collection, but have to create a table right?

Comment: If you want to specify headers you can override the AutoGeneratingColumn event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/customize_autogenerated_columns You could then use reflection on the bound type and work with an attribute such as Display https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Or to put that another way - no. You don't have to use a datatable. Assuming that's what you mean by table. Names of things matter.

Comment: @user1038502: What `ComboBox`? What type is `DbTableDefinitionController.TableTypeInformationRows`?